# Given $p \in [0, 1/2]$, what is a reasonable lower bound for $\Phi^{-1}(1-p)$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, normal-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\Phi$ (resp. $\Phi^{-1}$) denote the standard Gaussian cumulative density (resp. quantile) function. Given $p \in [0, 1/2]$, what is a reasonable **lower bound** for $\Phi^{-1}(1-p)$ only involving elementary functions like logs, eponentials polynomials, etc. ?

**Important note:** The bound $\Phi^{-1}(1-p) \ge 0$ is trivial and not interesting.
I am interested in a positive expression (in terms of elementary functions) that can serve as the bound.

## Observations

- Some simulations suggest $\Phi^{-1}(1-p) \ge \sqrt{2(\log(C/p)}$ with $C=1/10$. The bound is only "accurate" for very very small $p$.

[image]

- More simulations show that $\Phi^{-1}(1-p) \ge \sqrt{\log\left(\frac{1/p^2}{10\log(1/p)}\right)}$ is an even better approximation for $ p \le .25$ (even though I haven't succeeded in proving it formally). I've also plotted Ian's proposed approximation for $q(p) = \sqrt{2\log(\sqrt{2\pi}/p)}$
  [image]

Comment: what about the median ?

Comment: Median gives a lower bound of $0$ which is not good enough. I need a lower bound which is a function of $p$.

Comment: Isn't the quantile function increasing? Then for $p\in[0,1/2]$ 


$$\Phi^{-1}(1-p)\geq \Phi^{-1}(1/2)=m$$

Comment: $m=\Phi^{-1}(1/2)=0$ for standard Gaussian. No ?

Comment: It's correct, but you are not specifying any further condition, why isn't that good enough?

Comment: Bounding an expression means exhibiting a simplier expression (involving elementary functions like logs, exponentials, polynomials, etc.) such that the former always dominates the former. The bound $\Phi^{-1}(1-p) \ge 0$ is trivial and not interesting. I hope we agree on that.

Comment: Do you want accuracy in the $p \to 1/2$ regime or the $p \to 0$ regime? In the $p \to 0$ regime the best way I know uses repeated integration by parts to derive a sequence of upper bounds and a sequence of lower bounds.

Comment: I'm interested in both regimes, but the small $p$ (say $p \le 1/3$) regime most importantly. Any input welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some simulations suggest $\Phi^{-1}(1-p) \ge \sqrt{2(\log(C/p)}$ with $C=1/10$.

Comment: @dohmatob Could you comment on my answer, or accept it if you find it satisfactory?

Comment: @Ian, sorry for the delay. I was travelling. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way goes like this. Derive an upper bound:

$$\int_x^\infty e^{-y^2/2} dy = \int_x^\infty \frac{y}{y} e^{-y^2/2} dy \leq \frac{1}{x} \int_x^\infty y e^{-y^2/2} dy = \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x}.$$
For a lower bound:

$$\int_x^\infty e^{-y^2/2} dy = \int_x^\infty \frac{y}{y} e^{-y^2/2} dy = \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x} - \int_x^\infty \frac{1}{y^2} e^{-y^2/2} dy \\
\int_x^\infty \frac{1}{y^2} e^{-y^2/2} dy = \int_x^\infty \frac{y}{y^3} e^{-y^2/2} dy \leq \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x^3}$$

and combining these gives

$$\int_x^\infty e^{-y^2/2} dy \geq \left ( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^3} \right ) e^{-x^2/2}.$$

Thus

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left ( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^3} \right ) e^{-x^2/2} \leq 1-\Phi(x) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{x} e^{-x^2/2}.$$

Thus

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left ( \frac{1}{\Phi^{-1}(1-p)} - \frac{1}{\Phi^{-1}(1-p)^3} \right ) e^{-\Phi^{-1}(1-p)^2/2} \leq p \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{\Phi^{-1}(1-p)} e^{-\Phi^{-1}(1-p)^2/2}.$$

You now get an elementary lower bound in the small $p$ regime by getting a further lower bound for the LHS that only involves $\Phi^{-1}(1-p)$ through the exponential. Doing that requires substituting an upper bound for $\Phi^{-1}(1-p)$. One crude upper bound can be obtained by using the upper bound we just derived when $\Phi^{-1}(1-p) \geq 1$ (so it suffices to have $p \leq 0.15$). This bound is $q(p):=\sqrt{2\log(\sqrt{2\pi}/p)}$. In terms of this function:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left ( \frac{1}{q(p)} - \frac{1}{q(p)^3} \right ) e^{-\Phi^{-1}(1-p)^2/2} \leq p.$$

Now when $q(p) \geq 1$ you have:

$$e^{-\Phi^{-1}(1-p)^2/2} \leq \frac{\sqrt{2\pi} p q(p)^3}{q(p)^2-1}$$

and

$$\Phi^{-1}(1-p) \geq \sqrt{2 \log \left ( \frac{q(p)^2-1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} p q(p)^3} \right )}.$$

There is one additional requirement on $p$ which is simply that the argument of the log should be $\geq 1$ i.e. $q(p)^2-1 \geq \sqrt{2 \pi} p q(p)^3$, which constrains $p$ slightly more; numerically I find you're restricted to a slightly smaller range than $p \leq 0.137$. In the little range where this inequality fails but $\Phi^{-1}(1-p) \geq 1$, the previous inequality is still true but it is not telling you anything meaningful anymore.

This bound can be improved at the cost of further restricting its domain by restricting attention to $\Phi^{-1}(1-p) \geq C$ i.e. $p \leq 1-\Phi(C)$ for a larger $C$. In this case you get instead $q(p)=\sqrt{2 \log(\sqrt{2 \pi} C/p)}$ and a bound of the same form.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. I've added results of some experiments. It seems the adhoc (ad hoc because I haven't been able to prove it, just an observation) bound $\Phi^{-1}(1-p) \ge \sqrt{\log\left(\frac{1/p^2}{10\log(1/p)}\right)}$ is much better. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @dohmatob Basically the lower bound I started from proposes to solve the equation $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y^2/2} \frac{y^2-1}{y^3} = p$ for $y$. Since this function is not one-to-one, you should always be picking the larger solution...but unfortunately this function is also not onto $[0,1/2]$, so the solution doesn't even always exist. You get restricted to $p \leq 0.05$ or so. Once $p$ is indeed that small this bound gets pretty good (for example you commit less than 2% error in estimating $\Phi^{-1}(0.99)$).

Comment: (Cont.) I think one way to use this bound to get an elementary bound at least on this restricted range is to use a convexity argument in Newton's method: starting from some lower bound located to the right of the extremum (whose position can be determined analytically) you get a sequence of lower bounds out of it, and each finite stage is an elementary function of $p$. (These lower bounds don't converge to $\Phi^{-1}(1-p)$ of course.) But I do not really know how to get a decent elementary lower bound for $1-\Phi$ which is onto $[0,1/2]$.

Comment: Sorry, it's not just to the right of the extremum, it's to the right of the sign change in the second derivative, which is very slightly further to the right of the extremum. Thus I can use Newton's method to furnish lower bounds once $\Phi^{-1}(1-p) \geq 1.65$ or so (specifically the cutoff is the positive real root of $x^6-3x^2-12$).

Comment: OK, thanks followup.